# Application of integration

Tags: calculus

Hope anyone will help me with this question.If the above 2 regions of equal areas are fully rotated about x-axis,will their volume of rotation be equal?why?

Comment: You need to describe the two areas you're talking about for this question to make sense.

Comment: I wonder whether some askers around this point of the galaxy think others have the gift of guessing...

Comment: It is not generally true.  One area could be generally farther from the $x$ axis than the other.

Comment: sorry...but that's the real question...

Comment: If that's the "real" question, @user110721, then what is there "above"??

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you don't need calculus to see that this can't be true.

For instance, consider the square whose four vertices are $\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1) \}$ and then consider the square whose four vertices are $\{(1,0),(1,1),(2,0),(2,1) \}$

Comment: rereading the question, I just realized that the exercise refers to a specific picture. It will be hard to answer the question without knowing, but having read a few math textbooks in my day, I would guess they are trying to demonstrate that the answer is no!